# User defined string in another document

Tags: powershell

I need help with this code

```
$name = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input Connection String'
powershell -Command "(gc C:\ELK\logstash\bin\logstash.conf) -replace 'localhost:1521', '$name' | Set-Content C:\ELK\logstash\bin\logstash.conf"
```

I want user to define his own connection string and be able to launch the script again if user fat fingers and wont notice the typo.
If user inputs something but then remembers that he wants something else then the script wont work beacuse string "localhost:1521" wont exist anymore.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Would it be an option to just read in a second string?

Comment: Im sorry for late response but can you give example please?

Comment: See my answer for an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read in both, the pattern to replace and the replacement:

```bsh
$pattern = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input what you want to replace'
$name = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input Connection String'
powershell -Command "(gc C:\ELK\logstash\bin\logstash.conf) -replace $pattern, $name | Set-Content C:\ELK\logstash\bin\logstash.conf"
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I needed